# hide placeholder until someone clicked a image

Tags: jquery, html, css, placeholder

I have two pictures. If someone press one picture it should show a placeholder where you can write your email address.

```
<input name="email" placeholder=" Your Email Address">
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and jQuery / JavaScript you have so far? It would help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I added a `style="display: none"` to your input. That means it wont show up until someone clicks on the image.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="firstImg" name="email" style="display: none" placeholder=" Your First Email Address">
<input class="secondImg" name="email" style="display: none" placeholder=" Your Second Email Address">

<img class="firstImg" src="#" alt="I am a image" />
<img class="secondImg" src="#" alt="I am another image" />

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
      var imgClass = $(this).attr('class')
      $('input.' + imgClass).toggle()
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Put it in the html head, or last on you html-page.

Comment: it doesn´t work. should I write it witha <script> tag?

Comment: See my updated code. If you can't figure it out you should read about inserting javascript to HTML

Comment: I have updated the code, so you now have two img and depending on which you click a input will show. If you click on the img again the input will hide.

Answer (score -1):

// HTML Code

```
<input type="text" name="email"  class="mycode" />
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
```

Here you use Image where i place button clcik

// Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$( "#byBtn" ).click(function() { 
$('.mycode').attr("placeholder", "Type here to search");
});
});
```

Comment: Hey i don´t need a button I have two pictures and if I press one picture it should show a placeholder where you can write your email.